# StackOverflowErr with DynaForm example

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm getting a Stackoverflow when I try to run the DynaForm example from the ShowCase.

I tried other examples to see if I made an error while installing the extensions. pe:analogClock and pe:timeline work just fine.

Could someone please take a look and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Libraries:

- PF 5.3
- PFE 4.0.0
- commons-lang3-3.4

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttribute(Request.java:942)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getAttribute(RequestFacade.java:285)
    org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.RequestMap.getAttribute(RequestMap.java:47)
    org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractAttributeMap.containsKey(AbstractAttributeMap.java:62)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:182)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:96)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:260)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.base.AbstractDynamicData.getValue(AbstractDynamicData.java:110)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaForm.invokeOnChildren(DynaForm.java:243)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.base.AbstractDynamicData.invokeOnComponent(AbstractDynamicData.java:437)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaForm.invokeOnChildren(DynaForm.java:256)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.base.AbstractDynamicData.invokeOnComponent(AbstractDynamicData.java:437)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaForm.invokeOnChildren(DynaForm.java:256)
    org.primefaces.extensions.component.base.AbstractDynamicData.invokeOnComponent(AbstractDynamicData.java:437)
```

DynaFormControl:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.extensions.model.dynaform.DynaFormControl;
import org.primefaces.extensions.model.dynaform.DynaFormLabel;
import org.primefaces.extensions.model.dynaform.DynaFormModel;
import org.primefaces.extensions.model.dynaform.DynaFormRow;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DynaFormController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20120423L;

    private DynaFormModel model;

    private static List<SelectItem> LANGUAGES = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    @PostConstruct
    protected void initialize() {
        model = new DynaFormModel();

        // add rows, labels and editable controls
        // set relationship between label and editable controls to support outputLabel with "for" attribute

        // 1. row
        DynaFormRow row = model.createRegularRow();

        DynaFormLabel label11 = row.addLabel("Author");
        DynaFormControl control12 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Author", true), "input");
        label11.setForControl(control12);

        DynaFormLabel label13 = row.addLabel("ISBN");
        DynaFormControl control14 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("ISBN", true), "input");
        label13.setForControl(control14);

        // 2. row
        row = model.createRegularRow();

        DynaFormLabel label21 = row.addLabel("Title");
        DynaFormControl control22 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Title", false), "input", 3, 1);
        label21.setForControl(control22);

        // 3. row
        row = model.createRegularRow();

        DynaFormLabel label31 = row.addLabel("Publisher");
        DynaFormControl control32 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Publisher", false), "input");
        label31.setForControl(control32);

        DynaFormLabel label33 = row.addLabel("Published on");
        DynaFormControl control34 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Published on", false), "calendar");
        label33.setForControl(control34);

        // 4. row
        row = model.createRegularRow();

        DynaFormLabel label41 = row.addLabel("Language");
        DynaFormControl control42 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Language", false), "select");
        label41.setForControl(control42);

        DynaFormLabel label43 = row.addLabel("Description", 1, 2);
        DynaFormControl control44 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Description", false), "textarea", 1, 2);
        label43.setForControl(control44);

        // 5. row
        row = model.createRegularRow();

        DynaFormLabel label51 = row.addLabel("Rating");
        DynaFormControl control52 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Rating", 3, true), "rating");
        label51.setForControl(control52);
    }

    public DynaFormModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public List<BookProperty> getBookProperties() {
        if (model == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<BookProperty> bookProperties = new ArrayList<BookProperty>();
        for (DynaFormControl dynaFormControl : model.getControls()) {
            bookProperties.add((BookProperty) dynaFormControl.getData());
        }

        return bookProperties;
    }

    public String submitForm() {
        FacesMessage.Severity sev = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity();
        boolean hasErrors = (sev != null && (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.compareTo(sev) >= 0));

        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.addCallbackParam("isValid", !hasErrors);

        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getLanguages() {
        if (LANGUAGES.isEmpty()) {
            LANGUAGES.add(new SelectItem("en", "English"));
            LANGUAGES.add(new SelectItem("de", "German"));
            LANGUAGES.add(new SelectItem("ru", "Russian"));
            LANGUAGES.add(new SelectItem("tr", "Turkish"));
        }

        return LANGUAGES;
    }
}
```

BookProperty.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class BookProperty implements Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20120521L;  

    private String name;  
    private Object value;  
    private boolean required;  

    public BookProperty(String name, boolean required) {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.required = required;  
    }  

    public BookProperty(String name, Object value, boolean required) {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.value = value;  
        this.required = required;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  

    public Object getValue() {  
        return value;  
    }  

    public Object getFormattedValue() {  
        if (value instanceof Date) {  
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");  

            return simpleDateFormat.format(value);  
        }  

        return value;  
    }  

    public void setValue(Object value) {  
        this.value = value;  
    }  

    public boolean isRequired() {  
        return required;  
    }  

    public void setRequired(boolean required) {  
        this.required = required;  
    }  
}
```

dynaform.xhtml file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<ui:composition template="/templates/public/desktop/simple.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="mainForm">

            <h:panelGroup widgetVar="detail" id="detail">
                <p:messages id="messages" showSummary="true" />

                <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{dynaFormController.model}"
                    var="data">
                    <pe:dynaFormControl type="input" for="txt">
                        <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}"
                            required="#{data.required}" />
                    </pe:dynaFormControl>

                    <pe:dynaFormControl type="calendar" for="cal" styleClass="calendar">
                        <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{data.value}"
                            required="#{data.required}" showOn="button" />
                    </pe:dynaFormControl>
                    <pe:dynaFormControl type="select" for="sel" styleClass="select">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="sel" value="#{data.value}"
                            required="#{data.required}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dynaFormController.languages}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </pe:dynaFormControl>
                    <pe:dynaFormControl type="textarea" for="tarea">
                        <p:inputTextarea id="tarea" value="#{data.value}"
                            required="#{data.required}" autoResize="false" />
                    </pe:dynaFormControl>
                    <pe:dynaFormControl type="rating" for="rat">
                        <p:rating id="rat" value="#{data.value}"
                            required="#{data.required}" />
                    </pe:dynaFormControl>

                    <f:facet name="buttonBar">
                        <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                            action="#{dynaFormController.submitForm}" process="dynaForm"
                            update="_mainForm_dynaFormGroup" />
                        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset"
                            style="margin-left: 5px;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </pe:dynaForm>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

template simple.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: `StackOverflowError` will occur when there's an infinite recursion.

Comment: I agree. But where? I spent the whole Sunday on this. The code is copied from the showcases.

Comment: Where can be deduced by analyzing the stacktrace and see wich 'block' is repeating

Comment: I got the same error, you have just to :

1 - change the update on the commandButton   
`<p:commandButton 
value="Submit" action="#{dynaFormController.submitForm}" 
update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup"  />`

**update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup"**

2- add the id on the first panelGrid 
 `<h:panelGroup id="dynaFormGroup" widgetVar="detail" id="detail">`

**id="dynaFormGroup"**

Answer (score 1):

You have just to :

1. Change the update on the commandButton `<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dynaFormController.submitForm}" update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup" />` **update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup"**
2. Add the id on the first panelGrid `<h:panelGroup id="dynaFormGroup" widgetVar="detail" id="detail">` **id="dynaFormGroup"**